# 404 status for both a resource that is not yet defined and a requested data that is not found

Tags: rest, jersey, http-status-code-404, http-status-codes, jersey-client

Consider a situation when there is a jersey-client which returns 404 if some requested url is not found (i.e. the endpoint does not exist, there is a typo in a requested address etc.). But, at the same time, the resource itself using the same status to indicate that the requested endpoint is exist but the data we're looking for is not found.

Is there a good way (from design point of view) to distinguish between these two states in order to be sure what actually happened?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to distinguish 404 between entity doesn't exist and incorrect endpoint?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977069/how-to-distinguish-404-between-entity-doesnt-exist-and-incorrect-endpoint)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use `Content-Type` header to distinguish if 404 is because entity does not exist or url from request is not found. In first case the `Content-Type` is the same as for valid response i.e `application/json`, in second it's `text/html`.

Comment: Unfortunately in my case the content type will be the same - text/plain. Regardless of the nature of response.

Comment: In such case you may provide a response body with error message or use some custom HTTP header.

Comment: Right, the response body seems to be the solution at first glance - jersey client uses standard type of message like "null for blah-blah-resource" if a resource is not found. But, it doesn't look like a solid proof to build assumptions around it. So, as there is not too much I can do from the client's perspective I think that the new header is the way to go. Thanks.